# Why did Russia appoint Steven Seagal as a 'special rep.' for US-Russian humanitarian ties?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations

Why did Russia appoint actor [Steven Seagal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Seagal) as an intermediary figure in US-Russo relations? What is this role and what are Seagal's responsibilities? I know that Steven Seagal was recently granted citizenship in Russia in 2016, however, I'm curious about any underlying motives for appointing Seagal in this *unpaid* position? What political angle is Putin trying for?

Comment: Ok, who else thought that coreyman317 is pulling our legs or that it is **again** bragging of Steven "Special Op Special" Seagal? [But no, it is not a joke...](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/08/04/politics/steven-seagal-russia-special-representative/index.html).

Comment: Because they felt that the current state of US - Russia relations wasn't ridiculous enough?

Comment: Voting not to close - This question can be factually answered, and has been with an answer that has been accepted. It is not uncommon at all for celebrities to be involved in diplomacy.

Answer (score 8):

Same political angle that UN does for appointing Angelina Jolie something or other, or US Congress to invite Matt Damon to discuss education policies.

***Celebrity brings positive PR***.

Seagal personally brings one more possible niche benefit (aside from main benefit of him being available to appoint) - he's been a "pro-environmental" celebrity, which means he might be slightly more positively viewed by political left than, say, "Humvee" Schwarzenegger.

**UPDATE**

Found [the original announcement](https://www.facebook.com/MIDRussia/photos/a.480802735352506.1073741861.264205757012206/1425643507535086/?type=3&refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2F) (after screwing around searching for Russian wording, the blasted thing ended up being posted in English on Facebook, of all places. Bloody millenials and their bloody social networking. Even Russian MID is succeptible). This covers the role and responsibilities.

> Prominent actor, film producer and musician Steven Seagal has been appointed Special Representative for Russia-US Cultural Links, Cultural and Historical Heritage in a voluntary capacity. The special representative will perform his duties without any financial remuneration and **for the purpose of strengthening direct contacts, mutual understanding and trust between the Russian and American peoples**.
>
> It is expected that in his new role, Steven Seagal will **assist in the development and implementation of various projects for bilateral cooperation in the field of culture, arts, science, education, sports, public and youth exchanges, as well as participate in respective events in Russia and abroad, and maintain contacts with partners in the United States.** Moreover, the special representative will be involved in the **preservation of memorial sites in the US that are somehow connected with Russia, research into and the promotion of the Russian America legacy and other chapters of our common history that are of great interest for both nations**.
>
> We appreciate Mr Seagal’s willingness to use his experience and authority for promotion of the Russia-US public, cultural and humanitarian links as well as for building a more positive atmosphere in bilateral affairs. We wish him every success in this capacity.

As you can see the "why" is partially answered here - "**willingness and authority**".

Also, [RT article](https://russian.rt.com/russia/news/542423-sigal-mid-rossii) on the topic (which can be considered vetted by Russian government to an extent) supports my original assertion about Jolie:

> Уточняется, что в международной практике должность Сигала можно сравнить с работой послов доброй воли ООН.
>
> It is clarified that in international practice the position of Seagal can be compared with the work of the UN Goodwill Ambassadors.

Comment: Does Putin really worry much about pleasing US political left, especially with the current administration in the White House and the Congress ?

Comment: @Evargalo - who knows. I would never reject an opportunity to cover one extra angle, but I'm not Putin.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that the political left find Seagal more amenable...too many complaints about sexual harassment.

Comment: @ThorstenS. -  I would treat that consideration with far more likelyhood to be accurate if not for one word: Polansky.

Comment: Steven Seagal is a Trump supporter. Last year he wrote a fictional [book](https://www.amazon.com/Way-Shadow-Wolves-Hijacking-America/dp/0999497502) about the battle against The Deep State and mainstream media conspiracy. He's terribly unlikely to be attractive to the US left.

Comment: @defaultlocale - i guess i'm not up on pop culture. Last I know of him he had that big environmental movie where he was fighting Big Oil or something.

Comment: While the governator may be personally carbon-emitting at a high level, his policies and policy stances make him, generally, a more "moderate" Republican in the eyes of liberals, I'd think.  Certainly moreso than Steven Segal. But I certainly can't say that the Russians would look at it that way or not. +1 for taking a swing at this head-scratcher.

Comment: BTW, nobody paid attention to "willingness" part :) He's not necessarily "ideal for them", he's "ideal among those who were willing to do this" which may possibly have been a **somewhat** shorter list than entire IMDB :)